# Django - How to avoid white space in django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i'm using model.forms to get `<input>`data from user. also i'm using regular expression for that data.

**eg:**

> Input = tomorrow

then urls looking like :

> www.mysite.com/tomorrow/

**problem:**

when user put `tomorrow holiday` with whitespace i get error.

i tried .strip() in `views.py` to avoid white space. it gives error.

Comment: I guess you can use `''.join(stringname.split())`

Comment: @Akash  you can add your code and trace error

Comment: Your approach has many issues. Even if you solve the whitespace problem you should still deal with special characters such as `/`, `?`, or `&`. It is better to keep GET variables as GET variables, or encode them using `urllib.urlencode() `.

Comment: @ Selcuk absolutely :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) to format to valid URL and file naming.

```
slugified_input = slugify(<user-input>)
```